# In perl, how to loop through file, parse line and then compare values in the lines?

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm very new to perl and trying to figure out how to parse lines within a tab-delimited file and compare values from the parsed lines to a certain value and then print the line.

For example:
I want to print out all lines that have all numbers greater than 3.

> A 5.4 6.9 3.1
>
> B 10.2 3.4 7.6
>
> C 1.9 2.6 2.3

I would it to output

> A 5.4 6.9 3.1
>
> B 10.2 3.4 7.6

Thanks in advance

EDIT:  Sorry, my explanation was not clear and test case was not good. I would to find lines that have ALL numbers greater than 3.

For example: if I change 5.4 of line A to 2.4, I don't want the code to print this line because it contains a number less than 3.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work if one of my lines contain a number greater than 3 and a number lower than 3. For example if I change line A to "A 2.4 6.9 3.1", I don't want this line to print because it has a value less than 3. How would you do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program below will do this for you. It works by reading from the `DATA` filehandle so that the data can be incorporated into the program itself. To read the data from elsewhere you will have to `open` the source and read from that filehandle instead.

Each line is read into the `$_` system variable and divided into fields using `split` which, by default, splits `$_` on whitespace. The fields are put into the array `@data`.

The `grep` function returns the number of elements of a list pass the given test. The slice `@data[1..$#data]` is all of the `@data` array except the first element (as array indices start at zero).

The call to `print` prints `$_` if the count of elements greater than three is non-zero.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @data = split;
  print if grep $_ > 3, @data[1..$#data];
}

__DATA__
A 5.4 6.9 3.1

B 10.2 3.4 7.6

C 1.9 2.6 2.3
```

**output**

```
A 5.4 6.9 3.1
B 10.2 3.4 7.6
```

Comment: In one-liner flavor : `$ perl -F -lane 'print if grep { $_ > 3 } @F[1..$#F]' file`