# In perl, how to loop through file, parse line and then compare all values of the line?

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm very new to perl and trying to figure out how to parse lines within a tab-delimited file and compare values from the parsed lines to a certain value and then print the line.

For example: I want to print out all lines that have ALL numbers greater than 3.

> A 2.4 6.9 3.1
>
> B 10.2 3.4 7.6
>
> C 1.9 2.6 2.3

I would it to output

> B 10.2 3.4 7.6

Because B is the only line with all numbers greater than 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for... Can you add the source? It's the only language i understand :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [In perl, how to loop through file, parse line and then compare values in the lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899966/in-perl-how-to-loop-through-file-parse-line-and-then-compare-values-in-the-lin)

Comment: You accepted an answer in your previous question. If you can't modify that code so that all values are greater than three rather than any value (like you originally asked), then you need more help than SO has to offer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use Text::CSV CPAN module to parse tab-separated file into an array of arrays
- loop over all the records. For each record

  - Check if fields 1,2, and 3 are bigger than your threshold value. For just 3 fields, use a simple "if", for large # of fields, use `grep`
  - If all fields are bigger, print the record to STDOUT

Comment: @user839145 - there's List::Utils `all` command; or you can do a `grep` and count the length of resulting list - if it's the same as original # of fields, you are printing. OR, you can do a reverse, grep for elements `<=3`; and see if result is empty

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Assuming you have read a line from your file into `$inString`, you'd use:

```
($letter, $n1, $n2, $n3) = split('\t', $inString);
```

(The '\t' for the pattern is the tab character.)

Then check if $n1, $n2 and $n3 are all greater than 3 and, if so, print `$inString`.

This also assumes that you have a constant number of values on each line (three in your example). If this isn't always the case you can put the return value from `split` into an array and check all elements except for the first.